# Linear algebra eigenvalues and limits problem

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose a matrix $A$ has eigenvalues of $-0.9$, $0.8$, $\pm 0.5$ and $0.9 \pm 0.2i$. What can you say about $\displaystyle\lim_{k \to \infty} A^k$ when $k$ approaches infinity ?

Thanks.

Comment: I know A^k= p D^kp^-1, where it =A if k is odd and I(k) if k is even, but i don't understand the problem. And when K approaches infinity do i need to set two cases when K is even and odd?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} z^k = 0 \Leftrightarrow \vert z\vert<1
$$

Comment: Man how i didn't think about that. So i should say A^k= p D^kp^-1, and D^k = ( (-0.9)^k) and so on for other values when moving diagonally down the matrix, and therefore when k approaches infinity, the D^k is going to be the zero matrix and the lim of a^k =  0? is that correct?

Comment: Yep, that's correct.